# C++ How to represent a string in binary format?

Tags: c++, string, push-back

For some reason, I need to frequently generate strings use characters in {'0', '1', '2', '3'}. My current code use push_back() function and looks like:

```
string test = ""
test.push_back('0')
test.push_back('2')
test.push_back('3') // test would be "023"
```

I want to store the string in a char type or int type, and use binary form of each character to recursively generate the string. "023" would be stored in a char = '0010 1100'.

Do you think the binary operation is more time-efficient than push_back? If so, how to write the code.

Thanks!

Comment: How could you differentiate `10` from `101`, or any other binary strings that share a prefix?

Comment: Why would there be a performance difference between adding the binary representation of a number as a string vs the number as a string? In either case you are doing string concatenation, the string has no idea that one is "in binary" because they're just `char`s

Comment: @Purag Each character would exactly be represented by 2 bits.

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for your reply. In binary format, we might can use & | operators to represent this string in a number. Think about how to represent n*n adjacency matrix by a char array. In my case, I also want to store this string "023" in a char, which would be 00101100.

Comment: I would think reducing the number of allocations would trump bit squeezing digits inside a single `char`. Can you estimate the number of digits per string and reserve upfront to reduce them?

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, indeed I do reserve the space by test.reserve(N). I have already edit my question a little bit. Hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

You might use bitfield, something like

```
struct data
{
    unsigned char v1 : 2; // Can only store 0, 1, 2, 3
    unsigned char v2 : 2;
    unsigned char v3 : 2;
    unsigned char v4 : 2;
};
```

and then use

```
std::vector<data> v;
int nd_elem_in_last_item = 0; // to differenciate 00 from 0 and not there for final item.
```

So your data would indeed be more compact.

Answer (score -2):

make a string like `string s="0123"`.
And , use `next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end())` to generate all permutation of number consisting of 0,1,2,3.

Comment: OP implies his desired strings are variable length. This will only generate fixed length strings.